# Custom Scroll View Content size in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am diving deeper into SwiftUI and I try to implement pull to refresh functionality for Scrollview. As far as I know, there is no native solution both for iOS 13 and iOS14 so I try to implement Custom Scroll View using UIViewRepresentable.

I found some code on the Internet, adopted some lines for my app, but I keep struggling with the content size issue. The problem is that when I try to call my Custom Scroll View it required exact width and height but I have ForEach inside the Content View and it can be 500 or 15000 in height depending on number of cells, so I want ScrollView to autocalculate its height based on content.

My question is, how can I make this happen? I tried different approach but none of them worked - my scroll view stopped scrolling, the content inside scroll view moved above the visible area etc. Please, help if you know the solution.

My code for Custom Scroll View is

```
struct CustomScrollView<Content: View, VM: CustomViewModel>: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, viewModel: viewModel)
    }

    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
    let viewModel: VM
    let content: () -> Content

    init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, viewModel: VM, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.content = content
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let control = UIScrollView()
        control.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        control.refreshControl?.addTarget(context.coordinator,
                                          action: #selector(Coordinator.handleRefreshControl), for: .valueChanged)

        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
        childView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        control.addSubview(childView.view)
        control.contentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        
        return control
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) { }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var control: CustomScrollView<Content, VM>
        var viewModel: VM

        init(_ control: CustomScrollView, viewModel: VM) {
            self.control = control
            self.viewModel = viewModel
        }

        @objc func handleRefreshControl(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
            sender.endRefreshing()
            print("refreshed")
        }
    }
}
```

And I call it like in my SwiftUI View like this

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
        CustomScrollView(
            width: geometry.size.width,
            height: 20000,
            viewModel: viewModel) {
            TaskListMainView(presenter: presenter, viewModel: viewModel)
        }
```

When I call it this way one screen looks great as it approximately matches the height but another just stretches across the screen and looks like a mess.

How can I calculate the height of the content inside scrollView to make it fit the proper size and scroll?

My TaskListMainView consists of VStack with Picker and ForEach table inside it.

Comment: Remove this line ```control.contentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)``` and pass height ```CustomScrollView(
            width: geometry.size.width,
            height: geometry.size.height,```

Comment: @RajaKishan thanks for the answer but it didn't work. The scrollview stopped to scroll and the content went above the visible area of the screen (I can't see the top part of my TaskListMainView)

Comment: @AntonKlimenko have you managed to solve your problem?